# django 1.8 jinja2 add css class to field

Tags: jinja2, django-1.8

I want to be able to add a css class to a field in django 1.8 and jinja2.

Previously I was doing something like this:

```
{{ form.country|add_class('form-control')|safe }}
```

That was using `django-widget-tweaks` previously, but now that django 1.8 has native jinja support, what is the best way to do this?